# Редирект на страницу в зависимости от записи в cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie

Есть код, который делает запись в куки при выборе города и перенаправляет на него, если зайти заново на гл. страницу, то снова будет перенаправление на нужный город.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Cookie choose city
$('.cc_city-choose').each(function (index, value){
    $(this).click(function() {
        var city_name = $(this).attr('data-city');
        $.cookie("selected-city", city_name, { expires: 365, path: "/", secure: true });
        document.location.href = document.location+'/'+city_name;
    });
});
// Редирект на нужную страницу города, если есть запись cookie city
var city_cookie = $.cookie("selected-city");
if(city_cookie != null) {
    document.location.href = document.location+'/'+city_cookie;
}
});
```

Но есть ошибка, редирект идет на страницу такого типа **mysite.ru//city** а должно быть **mysite.ru/city**, то есть двойной слеш, помогите исправить ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил, нужно было убрать слэш :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Cookie choose city
$('.cc_city-choose').each(function (index, value){
$(this).click(function() {
    var city_name = $(this).attr('data-city');
    $.cookie("selected-city", city_name, { expires: 365, path: "/", secure: true });
    document.location.href = document.location+''+city_name;
});
});
// Редирект на нужную страницу города, если есть запись cookie city
var city_cookie = $.cookie("selected-city");
if(city_cookie != null) {
    document.location.href = document.location+''+city_cookie;
}
});
```